# Does scp over cp matter when copying to a remote SSH location?

Tags: ssh, scp

I am a little confused here.

Say I do the following: `cp /this x@x:x/to-this`.

Will not this already be a secure way of transferring the file since it uses the SSH protocol? Or is `scp` when used with SSH just preferred because of "double protection"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cp /this x@x:x/to-this
```

will copy file `/this` to file called `x@x:x/to-this` in your computer. It will not copy anything to the remote server. Simple `cp` does not support remote copying.

To copy to the remote server, you need to use `scp` (or other protocol).